# Bootstrap dropdown menu closes after clicking on dropdown on phone device

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have menu with dropdown. It works perfectly on computer. If I try it on phone device, menu will show after clicking on toggler. If I try to click on dropdown in menu it will close instead of showing what is in that dropdown. One more thing. If I open it on phone every single nav-item/dropdown-item is highlighted as active!

I tried removing fixed-top does not help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top"><img src="https://web-derka.cz/formprojekt/assets/img/logo.png" alt="..." height="66"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#profil-firmy">O nás</a></li>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                              Výroba
                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Výrobní program</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Strojní vybavení</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Konstrukce a technologie</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kvalita</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </div>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#kvalita">Reference</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#kvalita">Kariéra</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A div is not a valid child of a list. The problem is more apparent when the code is formatted properly. Be sure to follow the docs closely.

Comment: All information must be in your question post. Don't add new information and questions in comments. We would have no idea what kind of conflict your custom script introduces without seeing it.  Please revise the demo above to show the problem.